# Can't seem to add divide symbol in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I make a calculator program, however, it's just the divide button where the obelus sign isn't showing up, can someone tell me what's wrong with it?
All the other buttons work because I simply use "text = "+"" for example.

```
bttn_div = Button(calc, text = chr(246))
bttn_div.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 5)
```

Btw, here's an example of a working one, for reference.

```
add = Button(calc, text = "+")
add.grid(row = 4, column = 3, pady = 5)
```

Comment: Also, why don't you just use the obelus directly? `text = u"÷"`

Comment: I used `chr(247)` and it worked just fine. `chr(246)` is `ö`. But yes, you can use that character directly in your script. If you're using Python 3, you don't even need to specify a Unicode string.

Comment: Cannot insert directly, it just says: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file calculator.py on line 36, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: then declare encoding in first or second line - `#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` (if you use UTF-8). Normally Python understands only script file with ASCII characters - code 0 to 127.

Comment: Err.., with the # it reads the coding as a comment, so it doesnt actually do anything...also, if I try to remove the #, it gives me invalid syntax

Comment: Not true. Some comments are special.

Comment: @furas Python 3 allows any unicode character in code and assumes UTF-8 encoding for encoded bytes unless specified otherwise.  OP: if you are using 2.7, you should say so, *especially* when a question involves non-ascii chars.

Answer (score 2):

the Unicode value of '÷' is 247 try chr(247) you could see all Unicode values at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters